# Inconsistent data in a double precision field in Firebird with C#

Tags: c#, firebird

I have this code:

```
FbConnectionStringBuilder csb = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
csb.DataSource = @"SRVBUSINESS";
csb.Database = @"80EMPRE1.FDB";
csb.UserID = "SYSDBA";
csb.Password = "masterkey";                        
csb.Dialect = 3;

FbConnection conn = new FbConnection(csb.ToString());
FbDataReader read;
FbCommand command = new FbCommand("SELECT INICIAL FROM SALDOS18 WHERE NUM_CTA LIKE '600000%'", conn);

conn.Open();
read = command.ExecuteReader();

while (read.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(read[0]);
}
conn.Close();
```

I need to retrieve the values from a double precision field in a Firebird database, when I check the field in IBExpert I can see the correct value (229508.600008588), but when I execute my program I get this (8.59426113128662E-06). I know that Firebird stores the double precision values in an IEEE 754 binary format, but I need the right value for some basic operations with data from another fields.

Is there a way to get the decimal value directly from the query?

Comment: 229508.600008588 and 8.59426113128662E-06 are entirely different values. If this is the same record, that would indicate a serious bug in retrieval of data somewhere. If these are just random examples, then you should look at how you format a double precision in C#.

Comment: You are sure that you're querying the same table on the same database instance?

Comment: Yes, it's the same table and the same database instance. I've also thinked it was a bug, but tried to retrieve the data using another languages, drivers and programs, and the result is the same, only IBExpert shows the correct value, the other ones shows the value in IEEE-754 binary format

Comment: They do not show "binary format" - this has NOTHING common with binary. What you show is "decimal engineering" format aka mantissa-and-exponent format. And its ONLY difference from "fixed decimal" format is how it renders decimal point, but the very digits are all the same. So, again, the very sequence of digits from left to the right should match if the number is the same. They do not match. That means you quote DIFFERENT values in your question.

Comment: Try to fix your query to have one and only one value (row) in BOTH your program and IBExpert. `SELECT first(1) INICIAL FROM SALDOS18 WHERE NUM_CTA LIKE '600000%' order by 1 desc` and what values would be then ?

Comment: @Arioch'The there's no change, it continues giving me the same values 229508.600008588 in IBExpert and 8.59426113128662E-06 in my program

Comment: compare output row, column by column, for `select * from MON$DATABASE` in both connections

Comment: Is this column really a double precision, or are you maybe using a dialect 1 database and is this a `NUMERIC/DECIMAL` of size larger than 10? In that case the column is described as a double precision with subtype 1 or 2, which might account for the difference as not all drivers correctly account for this description and try to handle it as a pure double precision. What happens if you use `select cast(yourcolumn as varchar(20)) from ...`?